# JSON parser exception is observed for on fly JSON

Tags: java, json

I created a JSON file on the fly by using some runtime data and stored as string as like below:

JSON:

```
  {
        "ticketDetails": "kindle tracking ticket: TICKET0900060

        Iimpact statement: impacted due to year 2020 format handling issue,
        depending on the Gateway,
        user can be asked to
        try with another instrument.

        Timeline: 00: 00 SAP Internal Declines spiked to 300 +
            05: 22 AM flintron reported DECLINED errors since 0: 00 PST.

        As per TDO,flitron is not seeing clear metrics impact " }
```

Note: I just copied the exact json which i'm getting at runtime. It containse \n space and exactly like above.

I can see few JSONObjects like ticketDetails is having huge description and when I tried to parse the above string is leading to parse error.

I tried the below way to eliminate the parse error by using

```
String removeSpecialCharacterFromJson= jsonString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]","")

System.out.println(removeSpecialCharacterFromJson);
```

**Sample Output:**

kindletrackingticketTICKET0900060Iimpactstatementimpactedduetoyear2020formathandlingissue....[space between characters are removed and It's hard to read the string]

The above code removed all the special characters from the string and It will be successfully parsed. But the description is not having the space and It very hard to read the content after the above changes done.

I tried to escape the \s in the regular expression which is giving the original String value which is leading to parse exception.

```
String removeSpecialCharacterFromJson= jsonString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]","")
```

Is there anyohter way to handle this ? I just want to the ticketDetails to be readable format and It should not have any special characters and \n lines.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` in regular expression is not for *space* but for the **whitespace**
I guess that you may have some additional non allowed whitespace in your JSON string

Take a look at The JSON spec ([RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159)):

> Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six structural characters.
>
> ws = *(
>
> %x20 / ; Space
>
> %x09 / ; Horizontal tab
>
> %x0A / ; Line feed or New line
>
> %x0D ) ; Carriage return

Verify your values and look for improper whitespaces